# Rails SSE active / passive waiting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, ruby-on-rails-4, server-sent-events

I'm writing application in ruby and rails. I'm trying to use SSE for notifications for user. All works but i want to do passive waiting on HTTP connection and have no idea how. I think each request is processed on same thread and that's why, when i open connection and wait for messages, application stops working because server wait on another request. How can i do it? One way it to do some king of passive waiting and another is to process each request on other thread. Any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more common term and approach for what you're attempting to do is called "comet" or long polling.  SSE is HTML5 specific and thus newer.  I'm not sure if there's a Rails solution using SSE, yet, but Goliath (built on top of EventMachine) allows you to easily implement SSE if a non-Rails solution is an option for you.  Here's a fairly complete tutorial for doing so:

https://www.igvita.com/2011/08/26/server-sent-event-notifications-with-html5/

If you want to use Rails and a Comet solution, two projects I know about are the orbited gem (https://github.com/mallio/orbited) and Faye (http://faye.jcoglan.com/ruby.html).

Speaking specifically to your question about the app stops working, this is because you're only running one process and the app only handles one connection at a time in development environments.  The aforementioned gems alleviate this by using messaging servers to manage the open connections, returning control back to the Rails app (so it's no longer blocking).  In production, you could just fire up 10, 20 workers under Apache/Nginx, but this limits you to exactly that many connections.